# Use switch with number case and char case

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, case

I want to make a `switch` loop.

If input is from `1` to `5`. It will print a number. Else it will print `"this is not a number"`. And if the input is `'e'`. The `switch` loop should be ended.

I can make the number part, but I don't know how can I to make input with `'e'`. It just won't read. Here is my code:

```
int main() {
int i,a = 0;
printf("Write something:");
scanf("%d", &i);
    do{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("3");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("4");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("5");
        break;
    case 'e':
        a=1;
        break;
    default:
        printf("This is not a number”); 
        break;
    }
}while (a==0);}
```

My problem is I can't have input as `'e'` or any char. Because if I do that I will create a paradox loop or just don't work at all. Where am I wrong?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to mix characters and integers in the same (`int`) variable?

Comment: And what a _paradox loop_ is?

Comment: @UnholySheep I guess that is my beginner fault. The exercise tell me to do cases with numbers and char 'e'. So I kind of lost here and I try like this...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti When I make a loop that doesn't have an end. It won't stop running until taking all the memory. For me, with this code: It keeps printing "This is not a number" thousands of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat the integers as characters like this;

By the way, you probably want to read a new character each time through the while loop, otherwise you'll get stuck printing forever. The default case below allows us to break from the loop.

```
int main() {
    char i,a = 0;
    printf("Write something:");
    scanf("%c", &i);
    do{
        switch (i)
        {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
            printf("%c",i);
            break;
        case 'e':
            a=1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("This is not a number"); 
            break;
        }
    }while (a==0);
}
```

Comment: Which integers are you treating as characters? All of the values you are comparing in the switch are characters, not integers

Comment: @UnholySheep He says ` If input is from 1 to 5. It will print a number.` those integers (or any integers entered on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'e', you are actually saying "The value of 'e'". This is the ASCII value. The decimal value of 'e' is actually 101.

To make this work, you could use the `char` datatype. Read in the data as a char, and in your switch statement, instead of a digit, use a char instead. e.g.

```
switch (i)
{
case '1': 
  //do something
  break;
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, as this is correct as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Likely because it is not guaranteed that ASCII is used on that machine. While yes it's almost always ASCII there may be some cases where EBCDIC is used, for instance.

Comment: Or also that you missed the fact that `scanf("%c", &i);` has to be used as merely changing the variable's type is not enough.

Comment: Perhaps you're correct. Though I will say I didn't miss it, I just omitted the code (_Read in the data as a char_). This seems like a student's question, so it was my opinion that writing code for them doesn't help anyone. No big deal.

Comment: Well clearly OP is still a beginner so it might be worth mentioning that as well, as `%c` and `%d` will not yield the same result if you type "1". Also as shown in the edit log the "read as a char" was not there initially.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your switch as `switch(char)`. Convert your input to `char` (since it is 1 to 5 it can be a char). Then check for `case '1':` `case '2'` etc.

Edit: you need to take your input as a char

```
char i;
int a = 0
printf("Write something:");
scanf("%c", &i);
```

then

```
switch(i){
```

Comment: That doesn't fix OPs problem of not being able to input 'e'

Comment: Casting will not work. The ASCII value of 1 is still SOH. You'd need to convert it to a char, not cast.

Comment: You are right i will edit the solution. But the idea is he need a char switch to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this because in your scanf you specify that the input will be a decimal (%d).
If you want to check if it's a number or not, you have to deal with chars.
for example :

```
char c;
    while (42)
{
scanf("%c", &c);
if (getnbr(c) < 1 && getnbr(c) > 5)
     printf("%c", c);
else
     printf("This is not a number”); 
}
```

Something like that ... Hope i helped.

Comment: What is `getnbr()` supposed to be? Or the point of the endless `while(42)`?

Comment: I meant atoi() my bad.

Comment: And for the infinite loop, for me that was a detail in the example.

Comment: atoi is not going to work if you pass in a `char` as it expects a string as `char *`. If the goal was to repeat the loop 42 times that's not how it's done. It looks more like an infinite loop and in such a case you should use `while (1)` or `for (;;)` instead which is not misleading, this example looks more like pseudo-code. Pseudo-code is fine, but make it understandable.

Comment: It was indeed pseudo-code, sorry if it wasn't understandable enough.

Answer (score -1):

Others have suggested using %c so that your not mixing characters with integers but you need to be careful with the rest of the code. You may need a cast for the switch statement.

```
int i;
printf("Input:\n");
scanf(" %c", &i);

switch ((char)i)
{
    case '1':
        printf("Got number 1\n");
        break;
    case '2':
        printf("Got number 2\n");
        break;
    case 'e':
        printf("GREAT\n");
        break;
}
```

EDIT: Karston Koop asked a good question. My reasoning for the cast is simply that the integer i is not initialised. The formatted write from the scanf will only initialise the lowest/highest (depending on the hardware) byte of the entire 4bytes of the integer - the rest could be filled with garbage depending on what is on the 4bytes of stack reserved for the integer variable i. If it were a char all the bits would be initialised by scanf. As a result we only want the lower/upper byte for the switch statement as is and hence the cast. To get around this you could just initilaise i = 0. Then the cast becomes superfluous. I'll leave this in as it might be useful to someone in the future. Thanks to Karston for quizzing me on this.

Comment: ...or just define `char i;`

Comment: Fair point. But it may be worth leaving to highlight the possible stumbling point.

Comment: What happens without the cast?

Comment: @KarstenKoop because the integer i is not initialized you won't know what you've got in the remaining bits beyond the lower/upper byte (system depending) - hence it's likely to be something othe rthan the character code. If you initialise the int to zero at declaration you shouldn't need the cast. But such is nuances of C programming ;)

Comment: So what would be the difference between an uninitialized `int` and `char`? I don't see the cast having any effect.

Comment: The format write from the scanf will initialise all the bits of your uninitilised char. If you use an uninitialised int, only the lowest/upper (system dependent) 8bits will be initialised the rest will be filled with whatever garbage was in the remainder of the 4 bytes of the stack that the compiler/executable is reserving for your integer.

Comment: @Karsten Koop If you're not having any need to initialise the int then it just so happens that the 4bytes of stack where it resides was filled with zeros from the outset - but with C you can rely on luck you need to initialise the variable to be sure, the C language won't do this for you.

Comment: You are right. You should add this explanation in your answer. Although I'd say using an `int` with `%c` is wrong to begin with, and the cast is just a workaround of this mistake.